# PHP: Testing if Base64 encoded POST data is empty

Tags: php

Is there any reason why the PHP empty function would return true for valid base64 encoded data? Perhaps I should be using another function besides empty. The front-end app, build  in flex, tests to make sure the Bitmap that's converted to base64 isn't empty prior to the POST.

```
//codeigniter
$ImageData = $this->input->post('ImageData'); //ImageData encoded in base64 format

if (empty($ImageData))
    {
     //echo json error 
     return;
    }
```

Comment: Please show `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: No, there isn't. Apparently it is *not* valid base64-encoded data. Are you sure the name of the POST variable is exactly `ImageData`?

Comment: Yes, ImageData is correct. Hundreds of photos have been added but sporadically I get this error.

Comment: Also, empty doesn't test for the 'validity' of base64... base64_decode would test that...

Comment: @user1322092 Check the value of `post_max_size` and make sure you are not exceeding it. This would explain why it works most of the time and why the post data is empty when it doesn't. `var_dump(ini_get('post_max_size'))`

Comment: @DaveRandom, thanks for the great tip. I checked, and it's set for 8MB. My pics are on average only 50KB and wouldn't get near 8MB (controlled on frontend). I think it might be an issue with the flex application. I've added some additional logging statements (such as length for ImageDate when error occurs).

Answer (score 0):

The CodeIgniter function returns false if the post data is not set so :

```
 $ImageData = $this->input->post('ImageData'); //ImageData encoded in base64 format

if ($ImageData)
```

is enough to check $_POST['ImageData']

Comment: interesting, so perhaps no data was passed for ImageData for that session. I'll have to check the front end logic.  The error happens very infrequently.